# Get the browser history without using a browser

Tags: network, web-browser, privacy, logging

I would like to get the browsing history of a computer in my network (without running that web browser), is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Your browsing history is basically a file on the computer's disk. Depending on your attack scenario, many things are possible:

- **For someone who has access to your computer**, through a remote-controlled malware or just sitting at your desk while you're away, it is entirely possible to get that history file and read it "without a browser". If, however, you explicitly deleted your browser history, this is not possible.
- **For someone who is listening in on the network** however, it doesn't matter whether you delete your history or not because that person will be able to see all the (unencrypted) sites that you visited (effectively reconstructing your browsing history). It is worth pointing out that a malware or a surveillance tool installed by your employer could very well intercept your traffic locally.

Comment: can you give a name of this file who contains a history of browsing ?

Comment: It depends on the web browser. Best is to ask google (eg. "firefox debian history file"). However the history might be ciphered (or serialized, which makes it hard to read with a simple text editor).

Comment: i see , but i asked you the name of the file .

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible , of course the location of your browser history depend first of your web browser and secondly of your OS.
For example I know that in linux , in ubuntu distrib you can find lots of informations about mozilla web browser on the home folder of a user.
All of the informations are stored in sqlite database.

For see details : https://askubuntu.com/questions/412844/can-i-view-firefox-history-with-the-terminal

I hope this example can help you to see how web browser store some datas about users.

So if you have any access , any reverse shell with a console access for example you can find easily the history of the web browser that you target.

Comment: i dont find a solution yet